# Number of access hits to a vob

Tags: clearcase

I want to know the number of access(by users) to a particular vob.
How this can be achived.

Comment: What's a VOB? A [Video Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOB)?

Comment: @Cody: Vob Object Server, the ClearCase name for a source code repository.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a *direct* way to get the information:

- you can estimate the maximum concurrent users your vob can support, looking at the way you have configured your [lockmgr for that particular vob](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_perf_svr_lockmgr.htm)
- you can also do a `clearlicense` and see if you can reconcile the list of SID and a particular Windows group, supposing your Vob can be accessed only by that Windows group.